# Wrap code in structure - PhpStorm

Tags: php, html, phpstorm

In PhpStorm, if you're editing HTML, you can highlight some code, press <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + J</kbd> (default shortcut), and you'll get the option to **wrap** the highlighted code in an HTML tag of your choice. Useful for quickly wrapping something in a `div`, or if you forgot to make a `tr` before you made your `td`s.

I was wondering if there's an existing similar feature for PHP code?

For instance, if I have a line of code, I want to highlight it, and wrap it in a generic `for`-loop.

I was sure I'd seen this before, but it might have been Eclipse or NetBeans.

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/surrounding-blocks-of-code-with-language-constructs.html

Comment: @iainn - Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Create custom **Live Template** of "surround flavour" (so it can be used with that `Code | Surround with Live Template` action that you have mentioned) with desired content.

To have that "surround flavour" (such templates are listed that list) you have to use special `$SELECTION$` variable in your template.

- https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Live+Templates+%28Snippets%29+in+PhpStorm
- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/live-template-variables.html

---

Generic stuff for PHP also exist .. but Live Templates are more flexible as you can customize them.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/surrounding-blocks-of-code-with-language-constructs.html